# Fastest PHP data transfer

Tags: php, performance, connection, transfer

First: Sorry for my English its not my primary language.

I have an appliction that recives requests from clients and then searches for data in the database for presenting results.
The application consists of two parts. PART ONE recives the clients requests and then uses cUrl to comunicate with PART TWO  which searches for the right result data. What i need to inprove (in terms of speed) is the cUrl part. It was designed that way so if the whole PART TWO is moved to another server the connection between PART ONE and TWO will still work. Thats why PART ONE cant directly access the database. 
For connecting the PARTS cURl was used uptil now. I tried using SOAP but in terms of speed there is no inprovemend. I found thing like RMI or Cobra but those are for Java. And we already have a cache in the database to decrese search speed.

And the question:
Is there something quckier then cUrl and Soap ? The data send will always be only strings not files.

Comment: In my experience, cURL is a rather streamlined HTTP client. Are you sure that the bottleneck is in the data *transfer* (cURL), and not in waiting for a *response* from the server ("Part Two")? (And do you have actual measurements, or is that just your gut feeling?) Also, how far apart are Parts One and Two, network-wise?

Comment: I did check what is faster by making 1000 random requests. And it isnt that SOAP is slower, its just that the results are similar enough that changing from cUrl to SOAP wont make much diffrence. 
Network wise PART ONE and TWO are for now on the same server but PART TWO will be moved shortly. The client never connects to PART TWO . PART ONE functions as a connector/bridge between the client and the database. I also started looking for ways to compress the data.

Comment: @Aleksander: My point exactly: does the *transfer* of data (cURL or SOAP) actually slow you down, or is *waiting for server response* (from Part Two) the main cause of waiting? It seems that way - as changing transfer methods didn't get you much of an improvement.

Comment: If that is the case then until PART TWO gets moved to another server i wont know for sure. So time will tell. 
Thanks.

Comment: @Aleksander: Uh, actually, tools like Fiddler or Firebug will tell you what portion of the request is spent up/downloading stuff, and what is spent waiting for server to reply. That should give you some data.

Comment: 0_o. Firebug really does have a function like this. Didnt know about it. :) Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

SOAP will always have the overhead of needing to parse the XML, and likely the creation and destruction of your soap parser, using a simple REST Api with GET or POST variables will likely be slightly faster.

Comment: Didnt know about REST. Will look into it. Thanks for the tip :)